# i want to store files into two different folder locations but it shows error

Tags: php

Here is the code i write to store data separately into two folders but it shows error,
or can someone correct me to help  me out.
is there another way to store data into different folders?
it shows this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$folder1' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\scienceworld\admin\code.php on line 91` after move_uploaded_files.

```
if(isset($_POST['add_maths']))

{
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $datatype = $_POST['datatype']; // here i define two values PDF and Video
    $files = $_FILES["content"]['name'];

    $ext = pathinfo($files, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if ($ext == '.Application') 
     {
        $folder = "upload/PDF/";
     } 
     else 
     {  $ext == '.Video';//you can add allowed video extensions here
        $folder1 = "upload/";     (here it shows error)
     }


    if(file_exists($folder||$folder1.$_FILES["content"]['name']))
      {
          $store = $_FILES["content"]['name'];
          $_SESSION['status'] = "File Already Exist. '.$store.'";
          header('Location: 8thmaths.php');
      }
    else
    {
        $query = "INSERT INTO 8maths (title,description,datatype,files) VALUES ('$title','$description','$datatype','$files')";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        
         if($query_run)
            {
                // echo "Saved";
                 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["content"]['tmp_name'], ($folder,$folder1.$_FILES["content"]['name']);
                $_SESSION['success'] = "Data is Added";
                header('Location: 8thmaths.php');
            }
         else 
            {
                 $_SESSION['status'] = "Data is Not Added";
                 header('Location: 8thmaths.php');  
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error does it show exactly?

Comment: it shows this error: (Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$folder1' (T_VARIABLE) )@theminer3746

Comment: Well, you are missing a semicolon on `$ext == '.Video'`

Comment: yes bro i solved it after that it shows error after move_uploaded_files ($folder,$folder1.$_FILES["content"]['name']);

Comment: Check the opening bracket before `$folder,$folder1.$_FILES["content"]['name']` 
I don't think it should be there